# ASP.NET MVC - .NET Standard 2.0 libraries and probing privatePath

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, migration, versioning, .net-standard-2.0

**Project summary**

I am in charge of an older ASP.NET MVC project that's running on .NET 4.8. Due to its complexity and size there's no easy way to just "rewrite" it to .NET Core.

It utilizes `probing privatePath` in the `web.config` to achieve versioning of the whole app.

This makes it easy to change program versions on the fly, without having to "reinstall/copy" the app over and over again for each update.

**Example**

```
--bin
  --7.0
    --dll dir 1
      --some 3rd party dlls
    --dll dir 2
      --some other 3rd party dlls
  --7.1
    --dll dir 1
      --some 3rd party dlls
    --dll dir 2
      --some other 3rd party dlls
--patch
  --7.0.5.8
    --bin
      --dll dir 3
        -- version/project specific dlls
    --Content
    ...
    --Views
  --7.1.2.0
    --bin
      --dll dir 3
        -- version/project specific dlls
    --Content
    ...
    --Views
```

Now if I update the app (let's say to v7.1.2.0) all I need to do is to change the `probing privatePath` accordingly to the new version (which happens via a small tool where you can select one of the versions from inside the patch folder).

This is necessary (and handy) if you need to switch between versions if for some reasons the newer version won't work as intended.

**The issue**

For migration some libraries are switched to .NET Standard 2.0, acting as a bridge between .NET 4.8 and .NET Core (so the same libraries can be used in the old and other (newer projects).

Some of these .NET Standard 2.0 libraries are referenced by some of the projects .NET 4.8 libraries.

As a consequence it adds an additional folder to the structure

```
--bin
  --runtimes
    --win-x64
      --...
```

From what I've tested and gathered `probing privatePath` does not seem to work with these .NET Standard libraries.

If there's an update to one of these libraries they need to be replaced manually now (and unfortunately some people don't read installation instructions or just "copy" the runtimes folder over the old one, instead of completely replacing them, or just "forget" it completely, causing issues that were easily avoidable (by just reading the instructions properly!).

Also switching back and forth like before isn't possible anymore, since the runtime folder needs to be replaced with the one from that specific version.

The version switching tool could account for that, if it wasn't for IIS locking the libraries from the runtimes folder, when in use, which would require a complete shutdown of the specific application pool and waiting until the files can be (re)moved/placed.

**Question**

Is there a way to move the `runtimes` to something like

```
--bin
  --7.0
    //7.0 version specific
    --runtimes
      --win-x64
        --...
  --7.1
    //7.1 version specific
    --runtimes
      --win-x64
        --...
```

and have it loaded like everything else that's linked to `probing privatePath`?